# I want to convert a string to hash and divid into n bucket

Tags: hash, cryptography, uniform-distribution

Problem: I want to divide the M strings into N bucket as uniformly as possible.

One solution I was thinking is,

1. Create a hash of string
2. Convert the hash to integer by mapping ascii value of each character in hash
3. Sum up those ascii values
4. Divide the sum by N

Uniform distribution I believe will be solved by hashing but not sure converting to ascii will change anything.

Please suggest better solution if you have one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are many hashes available, some of which produce integer output.  For a non-cryptographic solution, try the [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) which can give a range of output integer sizes from 32 bit to 1024 bit.  Cryptographic hashes give fixed size outputs, so may need some processing to give an integer of the size you want.